# Why pincolor property is giving me an error with ti.map?

Tags: titanium

I am trying to include an annotation on ti.maps module on Titanium sdk 5.1.1.GA, but I am getting this error:

> message = "+[MKPinAnnotationView redPinColor]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10c2bb4e0";

has iOS updated MKPinAnnotationView ?, because it worked fine a couple days ago, and I took exactly the same code as in the official docs http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map

So the code I am running is :

```
var Map = require('ti.map');
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow();

var mountainView = Map.createAnnotation({
    latitude:37.390749,
    longitude:-122.081651,
    title:"Appcelerator Headquarters",
    subtitle:'Mountain View, CA',
    pincolor:Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
    myid:1 // Custom property to uniquely identify this annotation.
});

var mapview = Map.createView({
    mapType: Map.NORMAL_TYPE,
    region: {latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993,
            latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true,
    annotations:[mountainView]
});

var circle = Map.createCircle({
    center: { latitude: 33.74511, longitude: -84.38993 },
    radius: 1000, //1km
    fillColor: "#20FF0000"
});
mapview.addCircle(circle);

win.add(mapview);
// Handle click events on any annotations on this map.
mapview.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    Ti.API.info("Clicked " + evt.clicksource + " on " + evt.latitude + "," + evt.longitude);
});
win.open();
```

Does anyone has the same problem?

**EDIT:**

I think I found the problem, correct me if I am wrong it seems to be Titanium map module will be only supported with iOS SDK 9?, according with these changes : https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.map/pull/127/files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using TiSDK `5.1.#` or higher, you should compile with Xcode 7. It might be that certain features are also iOS 9+, but should not fail to compile

I notice in the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKPinAnnotationView/pinColor) the pincolor feature has also changed in iOS 9, so it could be your map module is not yet up-to-date, or the map module has not been fitted with the latest iOS change, but I think that not to be true.

Update your ti.map module to the latest! You can find it here: http://gitt.io/component/ti.map

Comment: Thank you @Rene Pot, the problem is also caused because and update of Titanium SDK, it automatically updates modules, so in my case I needed to indicate on the latest version that works with my sdk for 5.1.1.GA is this :

  <module platform="iphone" version="2.4.1">ti.map</module>
  <module platform="android">ti.map</module>